# Copy all files with certain extension, while maintaining directory tree

Tags: python

**My problem**:

1. Traverse a directory, and find all the header files, `*.h`.
2. Copy all of these files to another location, but maintain the directory tree

**What I've tried**:

I've been able to gather all the headers using the `os` library

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r'D:\folder\build'):
    for f in files:
        if f.endswith('.h'):
            print os.path.join(root, f)
```

This correctly prints:

```
D:\folder\build\a.h
D:\folder\build\b.h
D:\folder\build\subfolder\c.h
D:\folder\build\subfolder\d.h
```

**Where I'm stuck**:

With a list of full file paths, how can I copy these files to another location, while maintaining the sub directories? In the above example, I'd want to maintain the directory structure below `\build\`

For example, I'd want the copy to create the following:

```
D:\other\subfolder\build\a.h
D:\other\subfolder\build\b.h
D:\other\subfolder\build\subfolder\c.h
D:\other\subfolder\build\subfolder\d.h
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [shutil.copytree](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.copytree) with a **ignore** callable to filter the files to copy.

*"If ignore is given, it must be a callable that will receive as its arguments the directory being visited by copytree(), and a list of its contents (...). The callable must return a sequence of directory and file names relative to the current directory (i.e. a subset of the items in its second argument); these names will then be ignored in the copy process"*

So for your specific case, you could write:

```
from os.path import join, isfile
from shutil import copytree

# ignore any files but files with '.h' extension
ignore_func = lambda d, files: [f for f in files if isfile(join(d, f)) and f[-2:] != '.h']
copytree(src_dir, dest_dir, ignore=ignore_func)
```

Comment: In python3 `ignore_func = lambda d, files: [f for f in files if (Path(d) / Path(f)).is_file() and f.endswith('.py')]
`

Comment: @PauloMateus I like the approach you went with. However, your solution actually removes the `.py` files rather than everything else. There is a slight adjustment you would need to add: `and not f.endswith('.py')`. The addition of "not" achieves the goal of the original poster. Also, I recommend including the library import with your code: `from pathlib import Path`.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: as @pchiquet shows, it can be done in a single command. Yet I will show how this problem could be approached manually.

You're gonna need three things.

You know what directory you were traversing, so to construct the destination path, you need to replace the name of the source root directory with the name of de destination root directory:

```
walked_directory = 'D:\folder\build'
found_file = 'D:\other\subfolder\build\a.h'
destination_directory = 'D:\other\subfolder'
destination_file = found_file.replace('walked_directory', 'destination_directory')
```

Now that you have a source and a destination, first you need to make sure the destination exists:

```
os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(destination_file))
```

Once it exists, you can copy the file:

```
shutil.copyfile(found_file, destination_file)
```

Answer (score 1):

This will recursively copy all the files with '.h' extension from current dir to dest_dir without creating subdirectories inside dest_dir:

```
import glob
import shutil
from pathlib import Path

# ignore any files but files with '.h' extension
for file in glob.glob('**/*.h', recursive=True):
    shutil.copyfile(
        Path(file).absolute(), 
        (Past(dest_dir)/Path(file).name).absolute()
    )
```